# Google Matrix API - python return Nonetype error

Tags: python-3.x, google-maps-api-3, google-distancematrix-api

**"Update"**

*Finally resolved the issue, changed the try except to include TypeError and also use pass instead of continue in the except.

**"End of update"**

I wrote code to search for distance between two locations using Google Distance Matrix API. The origin location are fixed, however for the destination, I get it from an xlsx file. I was expecting to get Dictionary with Destination as the *Key* and the distance as *value*. When I run the code below, after certain loop I'm stumbled with this error code:

```
TypeError: Expected a lat/lng dict or tuple, but got NoneType
```

Can you help me understand the cause of the error? Here is the code (pygmap.py):

```
import googlemaps
import openpyxl

#get origin and destination locations
def cleanWB(file_path):
    destination = list()

    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=file_path)
    ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
    for i in range(ws.max_row):
        cellValueLocation = ws.cell(row=i+2,column=1).value
        destination.append(cellValueLocation)

    #remove duplicates from destination list
    unique_location = list(set(destination))
    return unique_location

def getDistance(origin, destination):
    #Google distance matrix API key
    gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key = 'INSERT API KEY')
    distance = gmaps.distance_matrix(origin, destination)
    distance_status = distance['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['status']
    if distance_status != 'ZERO_RESULTS':
        jDistance = distance['rows'][0]['elements'][0]
        distance_location = jDistance['distance']['value']
    else:
        distance_location = 0

    return distance_location
```

And I run it using this code:

```
import pygmap

unique_location = pygmap.cleanWB('C:/Users/an_id/Documents/location.xlsx')
origin = 'alam sutera'
result = {}
for i in range(len(unique_location)):
    try:
        result[unique_location[i]] = pygmap.getDistance(origin, unique_location[i])
    except (KeyError, TypeError):
        pass
```

If I print results it will show that I have successfully get 46 results

> > > result
> > >           {'Pondok Pinang': 25905, 'Jatinegara Kaum': 40453, 'Serdang': 1623167, 'Jatiasih
> > >           ': 44737, 'Tanah Sereal': 77874, 'Jatikarya': 48399, 'Duri Kepa': 20716, 'Mampan
> > >           g Prapatan': 31880, 'Pondok Pucung': 12592, 'Johar Baru': 46791, 'Karet': 26889,
> > >            'Bukit Duri': 34039, 'Sukamaju': 55333, 'Pasir Gunung Selatan': 42140, 'Pinangs
> > >           ia': 30471, 'Pinang Ranti': 38099, 'Bantar Gebang': 50778, 'Sukabumi Utara': 204
> > >           41, 'Kembangan Utara': 17708, 'Kwitang': 25860, 'Kuningan Barat': 31231, 'Cilodo
> > >           ng': 58879, 'Pademangan Barat': 32585, 'Kebon Kelapa': 23452, 'Mekar Jaya': 5381
> > >           0, 'Kampung Bali': 1188894, 'Pajang': 30008, 'Sukamaju Baru': 53708, 'Benda Baru
> > >           ': 19965, 'Sukabumi Selatan': 19095, 'Gandaria Utara': 28429, 'Setia Mulya': 635
> > >           34, 'Rawajati': 31724, 'Cireundeu': 28220, 'Cimuning': 55712, 'Lebak Bulus': 273
> > >           61, 'Kayuringin Jaya': 47560, 'Kedaung Kali Angke': 19171, 'Pagedangan': 16791,
> > >           'Karang Anyar': 171165, 'Petukangan Selatan': 18959, 'Rawabadak Selatan': 42765,
> > >            'Bojong Sari Baru': 26978, 'Padurenan': 53216, 'Jati Mekar': 2594703, 'Jatirang
> > >           ga': 51119}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue to include `TypeError` in the `Try Except`. And also use `pass` instead of `continue`

```
import pygmap

unique_location = pygmap.cleanWB('C:/Users/an_id/Documents/location.xlsx')
origin = 'alam sutera'
result = {}


#get getPlace
for i in range(len(unique_location)):
    try:
        result[unique_location[i]] = pygmap.getDistance(origin, unique_location[i])
    except (KeyError, TypeError):
        pass
```

I skipped some locations using this solution though.